# Count character ocurrence in text file using PHP

Tags: php, regex, file

```
$count = 0;
$myFile = "file.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');

while(!feof($fh)) 
{
    $Char1 = fgetc($fh);
    if($fh == "a") 
    {
        echo $fh;
        $count++;
    }
}
fclose($fh);

echo "Total 'a' inside File: " . $count;
```

Content of : **file.txt**

> asdasdadaffl;sdgkjsdhfjkghsdfghsdkfvndm,vncmvskjdhfdafhaldfadcnasc
>   adkfjhasdjkalfhadlhhfdskdfhdjkfasf
>   aksdjfhajksdfhjkasdfhakdfasdkcsncandkn
>
> asdkjfhaskdfcnslkjdshfa
>   asdfjkadhfkashdfdknscnaskdjf

What i'm trying to do here is to count how many occurrences of character 'a' are found in this file. Please help.

Comment: You can't compare an opened file handle with a string; replace `$fh == "a"` with `$Char1 == "a"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not just use something like

```
$count = 0;
$myFile = "file.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
while(!feof($fh)){
    $fr = fread($fh, 8192);
    $count += substr_count($fr, 'a');
}
fclose($fh);
echo 'there are ', $count, " a's";
```

Comment: may i ask what's 8192 for? at this line --> $fr = fread($fh, 8192);

Comment: its the amount of bytes that is to be read each time and I just took that number off the PHP's website

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$path = "file.txt";
$file = file_get_contents($path);
$count = preg_match_all("/a/", $file, $matches);
```

Here we are using:

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to read a file into a string.

[preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to do a global regular expression match for the string.

Alternatively you can do:

```
$path = "file.txt";
$count = substr_count(file_get_contents($path), "a");
```

**EDIT:**

As Anthony note, if you are planing to work with exceptionally large files, you will need to use `fopen`.

Comment: sir what if to use a fopen method?

Comment: @Detective7 You dont need fopen for this.

Comment: You might need to if the file is exceptionally large